# Bootstrap. How to add bottom margin for mobile screen only?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this HTML code

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="titulo">
                    <h2 class="title-section font-switch">Algunos tecnologias que manejamos</h2>
                    <span>Si no vez el que necesitas pregunta, a veces no ponemos todos</span>
                </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                <div class="row center">
                    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-0  vcenter">

                        <a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <div class="caption-content">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <img src="img/csharp.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-0  vcenter">


                        <a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <div class="caption-content">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <img src="img/java.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-3  col-sm-offset-0  vcenter">

                        <a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <div class="caption-content">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <img src="img/cmasmas.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                        </a>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-3  col-sm-offset-0  vcenter">

                        <a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <div class="caption-content">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <img src="img/androidstudio.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                        </a>



                    </div>



                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
```

this is displayed as it:

[image]

but when screen size is changed to mobile screen  the view is it:

a margin is needed (top or bottom or both)
[image]

I know I could add it with Media queries, but I believe if I am using bootstrap I must to use less posible the media queries.

How can I add a margin only for mobile screen?

Comment: Bootstrap's [media queries](https://scotch.io/tutorials/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries). That tutorial goes through bootstrap's own break points. No reason you couldn't add one of those media queries to your own css.

Comment: Bootstrap 5: `<div class="mb-2 mb-md-0"></div>
`

Answer (score 224):

If you are using Bootstrap 4, you can do it with spacing utilities:

```
 <div class="mb-4 mb-md-0"></div>
```

This says:

`mb-4`: use a bottom margin size of 4 for all screens (xs and up)

`mb-md-0`: use a bottom margin size of 0 for medium (md) screens and up

Comment: I wish Bootstrap's documentation explained this as succinctly as this.

Comment: Same for Bootstrap 5 ;)

Comment: How can you invert it, so that you have it on md and down?

Comment: In Bootstrap 5.3, I am using ms(as in "start", formerly "left") and me (as in "end")

Comment: Yep, the documentation is horrible, thank goodness we have Stackoverflow. Flimtix, bootstrap applies ever thing from small to extra large. So to apply margin to small screen start and end, and not use margin above this we would use the following. " ms-4 me-4 ms-md-1 me-md-1"

Answer (score 15):

You can add div with `.visible-xs` which only display on xtra small screens and add your custom class margin, for example:

```
<div class="mobile-margin visible-xs"></div>
```

with custom css margins:

```
.mobile-margin { margin-top: 0px; }
```

and the margin will display only for xs screen.

Comment: I hoped there was a built-in solution but this works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I have this issue a lot so I created a custom class called "mobile-space" which I add to divs that need a margin-top only in mobile:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.mobile-space {margin-top:10px;}
}
```

Personally, I'd go this route WITH a media query rather than adding unnecessary html markup like divs.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 4 allows hidden-sm-up classes, which toggles one object from sm to xl.

Then, you can add a column between each image column, and add this class that will be visible only in mobile devices.

More info: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/

"Available classes"

Sorry my english, :D

Answer (score 2):

Simply apply a global style to **all columns** that have a dedicated mobile-column-size in the first place:

```
# Add global bottom margins to mobile columns except full width
@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
   .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, 
   .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6,
   .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9,
   .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11 {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
   }
}
```

If you need certain columns to have alternative margins, just add a dedicated class to those. This approach keeps the HTML clean in most cases.

Comment: This can be simplified to: `@media all and (max-width: 767px) { [class^='col-sm-'] {margin-bottom: 20px; } }`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .vcenter img {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

Assuming `vcenter` is the common div wrapping those images.

Answer (score -2):

Bootstrap doesn't provide something for managing margins or paddings, but you could do something like this: [jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/dhc96r7t/). Where you set the margin to a div with visible-xs class.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <p>123123</p>
  <div class="xs-margin visible-xs">
  </div>
  <p>asdasdadasd</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

with css:

```
.xs-margin {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```