# how to add 0 padding only on mobile device using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, cross-platform, padding

I want `padding: 0` only on mobile `sm` devices

I tried [this](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/56852251/3836908) as reference and I also tried below code, but nothing works

> Since `col-*-12` has default padding of 15px on right and left i want this `col-` value to be **zero** only on mobile.
>
> in more detail only on mobile device the padding should be zero, and all other device the padding should add from `col-*-12`

Below a short example I tried:

**FYI**

I can make `padding: 0` only on mobile with this class `col-lg-12 col-md-12 px-0 px-md-2`, I don't want to override `padding-right` and `padding-left` from `col-*-12`, so I want to make use of padding from `col-*-12`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid bg-white shadow-sm pt-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 px-4 px-sm-0">
      <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb shadow-sm rounded-0-sm">
          <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li class="breadcrumb-item">
            <a href="/ads/car/">
              this is categroy
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="breadcrumb-item">
            this if file name
          </li>
          <li class="breadcrumb-item text-secondary text-wrap text-break">
            cate file name
          </li>
        </ol>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile devices has an `xs` size and not `sm`.

You can use:

````
<div class="container-fluid bg-white shadow-sm pt-3">
  <div class="row">

//use xs property on mobile devices
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 px-xs-0 px-sm-4">
      <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb shadow-sm rounded-0-sm">
          <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li class="breadcrumb-item">
            <a href="/ads/car/">
              this is categroy
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="breadcrumb-item">
            this if file name
          </li>
          <li class="breadcrumb-item text-secondary text-wrap text-break">
            cate file name
          </li>
        </ol>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>```
````

Answer (score 0):

you can using media query :
xl: min-width: 1200px,
lg: min-width: 992px,
md: min-width: 768px,
sm: min-width: 576px,
xs: min-width: 0.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp